# I want to merge two tables without any primary keys

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

We cannot create any additional column 
Please keep that in mind

The whole intention of this script is to merge data into my temp table
when the data is matching don't have to do any thing.
if some data is present in #temp_cqm_class_template_xref and not in cqm_class_template_xref_temp then those data's has to be deleted from #temp_cqm_class_template_xref table

if it is the other way it has to be inserted into the #temp_cqm_class_template_xref table

```
IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#temp_cqm_class_template_xref') IS NOT NULL
    DROP TABLE #temp_cqm_class_template_xref;

CREATE TABLE #temp_cqm_class_template_xref (
    [template_name] [VARCHAR](30) NOT NULL
    ,[measure_id] [INT] NOT NULL
    ,[cqm_item_mstr_id] [INT] NOT NULL
    ,[created_by] [INT] NOT NULL
    ,[modified_by] [INT] NOT NULL
    ,[create_timestamp] [DATETIME] NOT NULL
    ,[modify_timestamp] [DATETIME] NOT NULL
    );

MERGE INTO #temp_cqm_class_template_xref AS t
USING cqm_class_template_xref_temp AS s
    ON (
            t.template_name = s.template_name
            AND t.measure_id = s.measure_id
            AND t.cqm_item_mstr_id = s.cqm_item_mstr_id
            )
WHEN NOT MATCHED
    THEN
        INSERT (
            template_name
            ,measure_id
            ,cqm_item_mstr_id
            ,created_by
            ,modified_by
            ,create_timestamp
            ,modify_timestamp
            )
        VALUES (
            s.template_name
            ,s.measure_id
            ,s.cqm_item_mstr_id
            ,s.created_by
            ,s.modified_by
            ,s.create_timestamp
            ,s.modify_timestamp
            )
WHEN NOT MATCHED BY target
    THEN
        DELETE;
```

When I run this script, I get the following error:

> Msg 10711, Level 15, State 1, Procedure
>   ngdev_cqm_class_template_xref_bcp_upld, Line 88 An action of type
>   'INSERT' is not allowed in the 'WHEN MATCHED' clause of a MERGE
>   statement

Comment: Is there a question here? What problem(s), errors are you getting? Without ddl and some sample data for your base table this is going to be challenging.

Comment: Msg 10711, Level 15, State 1, Procedure ngdev_cqm_class_template_xref_bcp_upld, Line 88
An action of type 'INSERT' is not allowed in the 'WHEN MATCHED' clause of a MERGE statement.

Comment: You say "*if some data is present in #temp_cqm_class_template_xref and not in cqm_class_template_xref_temp then those data's has to be deleted from #temp_cqm_class_template_xref table. if it is the other way it has to be inserted into the #temp_cqm_class_template_xref table*"  The fastest/safest/most reliable way to do this is to just `DELETE From #temp_cqm_class_template_xref table` and then INSERT everything from `cqm_class_template_xref_temp` into `#temp_cqm_class_template_xref table`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may try something like left join and figure out what columns are null
in the opposite table;
According to your logic  This might help you

```
update t
set t.template_name=null,
t.measure_id = null,
 t.cqm_item_mstr_id = null
#temp_cqm_class_template_xref t Left join cqm_class_template_xref_temp s on 
t.template_name = s.template_name
            AND t.measure_id = s.measure_id
            AND t.cqm_item_mstr_id = s.cqm_item_mstr_id
delete from #temp_cqm_class_template_xref
where measure_id is null and cqm_item_mstr_id is null and  and template_name is null
```

Answer (score 2):

Merge is not a good technique to use. see:
https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/3074/use-caution-with-sql-servers-merge-statement/

Merge is hard to debug and very hard to maintain later when you have problems with the data that it is trying to merge. Don't ever use it.

Instead write an insert using a select instead of a values clause and write a delete.

Comment: I'm trying that...
but not getting any write approch. Thanks